# SAS proc sort nodupkey keeping the wrong record

Tags: sas

```
proc sort data=test;
 by col1 col2;

proc sort data=test nodupkey;
 by col1;
```

test:

```
col1 col2
2018   D
2018   W
```

I expect the 'D' record to survive but hte output has the 'W' record sometimes and sometimes the 'D' record.

Comment: Check your log, what does it say? I cannot reproduce your problem and others won't so it's likely you're doing something else wrong and we cannot help with that without a reproducible example.

Comment: The log just says that 1 duplicate was removed. there is no error. The problem is..i was expecting it will keep the first record as per the first proc sort, but it is keeping the 'W' record.

Comment: Post the log and output from the code in my answer below.

Comment: You say "sometimes" has 'W' record?  So you have multiple values of col1.  And sometimes NODUPKEY is keeping the first record from each key, and other times it's keeping a different record from that key?  I wonder if you could have options NOSORTEQUALS set?  That would tell SAS not to worry about maintaining record order within BY groups when it sorts.  You could try `proc sort data=test  nodupkey equals;`

Comment: Where is the data stored?  Is this SAS datasets, or is it on a SQL server or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data test;
input col1 col2 $;
cards;
2018 D
2018 W
;;;;
run;

proc sort data=test; by col1 col2;
run;

proc sort data=test out=new nodupkey;
by col1;
run;;

proc print data=new;
run;
```

Comment: It gives correct output. Let me try by adding out=new.

Comment: @Victor I don't think adding out=new should change the behavior of which record survives NODUPKEY.  Any chance you could try to make a little example that reproduces your original problem?

Comment: @Quentin Agreed, this shouldn't have solved his issue, it's likely somewhere else then.